# Is it possible to add a uniqueness constraint accross two different but associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I have the models `Account` and `User`. Both models have an `email` attribute.

An Account `has_many :users` and a User `belongs_to :account`

I would like to validate the uniqueness of the `email` accross both models when an `Account` is being created so the `Account` email is invalid if it's taken by a `User` (since the account email later becomes the admin user email).

I added a scope to the `email` constraint in the `Account` model but it is not working (the form is not being rejected).

*Account model:*

```
has_many :users
validates :email,   uniqueness: { scope: :users, case_sensitive: false }
```

What is the correct way to implement this? Do I need to add an index to the DB?

Comment: I thought `scope` was column-based, e.g., intra-model? In the past I’ve done things like this with a regular custom validation method—I don’t know if it’s currently supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: Backing up what Dave said with https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, `validates_uniqueness_of` is a part of ActiveRecord and not ActiveModel and is basically a just a fancy wrapper around `errors.add(...) if where(column_name: attribute).exist?`. `scope` just adds an AND clause to the query.

Answer (score 2):

An application level validation doesn't actually guarentee the uniqueness of your data - it merely catches a lot of the cases where users try to input duplicates and provides feedback.

So while you could naively implement a custom validation that queries both tables it won't even survive [the race condition caused by a double clicking senior citizen](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) or any insertion method that circumvents validations.

[image: Flow chart of paralell requests from Thoughtbot]

Since there is no way (AFAIK) to create indices across tables so you might want to just restructure your domain and add an "owner" (call it whatever you want) to the accounts table:

```
class AddOwnerToAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :accounts, :owner, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: 'users' }
  end 
end
```

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, 
    class_name: 'User',
    inverse_of: :owned_accounts
  delegate :email, to: :owner
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :owned_accounts,
    class_name: 'Account',
    foreign_key: :owner_id,
    inverse_of: :owner
end
```

Comment: I like this suggestion. The only thing that I think is missing is a check that an `Email` has only one associated `User` or `Account` record. Otherwise when multiple records can point to the same email record then you basically have the same problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @spickermann yeah I just though of that and I can't really come up with a good solution that guaentees the uniqueness without resorting to a polymorphic  association so I axed it in favor of the second solution.

Comment: @spickermann feel free to use it if you can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative method based on a separate table and a polymorphic assocation:

```
class CreateEmailAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :email_addresses do |t|
      t.string :email, unique: true
      t.references :entitity, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :email_addresses, [:entity_type, :entity_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

```
class EmailAddress < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :entity_id, scope: :entity_type
  belongs_to :entity, polymorphic: true
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :email_address, 
    as: :entity,
    dependent: :destroy
  delegate :email, to: :email_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_address
end
```

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :email_address, 
    as: :entity,
    dependent: :destroy
  delegate :email, to: :email_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_address
end
```

It avoids having to restructure your domain or create a user simply to create a email but will cause issues with authentication libraries such as Devise as well as lacking a real foreign key to guarentee referential integrity which can lead to orphaned records.

IMO not a great solution as it most likely will create as many problems as it solves.

Answer (score 1):

This an only be achieved with a [custom validation method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods).

```
validate :email_unique_for_account_and_user

private

def email_unique_for_account_and_user
  if User.where(email: email).where.not(id: id).exists? || 
     Account.where(email: email).where.not(id: id).exists?
    errors.add(:email, :taken)
  end
end
```

IMO it is not possible to define a unique index over multiple database tables.

Comment: The key caveat here is that this doesn't actually guarentee uniquess in the same way that a constraint does and its still very likely that you will end up with duplicate data.

Comment: You are right, with this solution you might end up with duplicates when you run into race conditions.